# How do I validate Jssor ThumbnailTemplate within a div element?

Tags: validation, templates, thumbnails, jssor

I've been able to validate everything in the Simple Image Slider except the element "ThumbnailTemplate".

```html
<!-- ThumbnailNavigator Skin Begin -->
    <div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort03" style="position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 60px; left:0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div style=" background-color: #000; filter:alpha(opacity=30); opacity:.3; width: 100%; height:100%;"></div>

                    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
            <div data-u="prototype" class="p" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 62px; HEIGHT: 32px; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;">
                <div class=w><ThumbnailTemplate style=" WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;"></ThumbnailTemplate></div>
                <div class=c style="POSITION: absolute; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #000; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
```

Comment: Add more context. Add appropriate tags to attract those who are interested, or this question is buried in hundreds of new questions without receiving response.

Comment: Revised the question and added more tags and context.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by html tag `<ThumbnailTemplate style=" WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;"></ThumbnailTemplate>`.

It has already been fixed in following manner `<div u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>`.

Please download the latest version.